# correct steps to release an app with gpl v3 license

Tags: licensing

I'm about to release a little demo app for play framework in github, and I want everyone to be able to have a look at it, learn from it, and use it as a base for their own developments...

what would be the best license for such a thing (I was thinking about gplv3) and what would be the steps to make it comply with that license?

Comment: The GPL and most other licenses do not impose restrictions on the code, but on the users of the code. Certainly it's a given that GPL code needs to be provided as source code, but that's hardly surprising.

Comment: I mean if there's any disclaimer I should add the each source file or anything like that... how shall I state the license I'm using and so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The process involves adding two elements to each source file of your
>   program: a copyright notice (such as “Copyright 1999 Terry Jones”),
>   and a statement of copying permission, saying that the program is
>   distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License (or the
>   Lesser GPL).

See "[How to use GNU licenses for your own software](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html)" from the FSF for more details.

---

With regards to selecting a license, the following resources should be useful:

- [three.org License Chooser](http://three.org/openart/license_chooser/)
- [ZDNet: How to pick an Open Source License](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/howto-pick-an-open-source-license-part-1/130)
- [Choosing an Open Source License](http://airs.com/ian/essays/licensing/licensing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Customarily you would include the standard GPL file and call it LICENSE. You might also put something like "this code us released under the GPL; see the file LICENSE for details" in the README or similar. The GPL also actually explains how to use it; see http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html and in particular "How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs" near the end. (I would recommend reading the license for other reasons, too, if you are about to apply it to a copyrighted work of yours!)

There is no requirement to modify each source file, although it might be a nice gesture towards your user, especially if some files are useful in isolation.